# How to integrate Jquery seat chart with codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am implementing a ticket booking website using Codeigniter. Now i want to design a seating arrangement system. How can i do this using codeigniter? When googled i ended up with jquery seat chart. But i was not able to integrate it with codeigniter.

Comment: Please update your question with the library url (or github repository url).

Comment: Also show us what you tried

Answer (score 0):

Just get the data from jquery plugin and submit it to your controller.